# vue single file component - self import

Tags: vue.js

Is there any possibility to import the same SFC? I mean something like:

test.vue:

```
<template>
  <ul v-for="(item, index) in menuLevel">
    <li>
      {{item.name}}
      <test :data="item" v-if="item.children && item.children.length"></test>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can read about it in the documentation under [Recursive Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Recursive-Components).

You need to make sure you specify the component's [`name`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#name) in the component options object and you're all set.

Comment: And also check for possibility of infinite loops

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I have check: item.children && item.children.length :)